# Bases of Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $\{e_1, e_2\}$ is a basis of $V$, and dimension of $V$ is 2. Assume that 
$$ M(T,\{e_1,e_2\}) = \left [\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array} \right] $$

Find a basis $\{v_1,v_2\}$ of $V$ s.t.

$$ M(T,\{e_1,e_2\}) = \left [\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right]$$

What I've tried so far:
$$ M(T,\{e_1,e_2\}) = \left [\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 \end{array} \right] $$

$T(e_1) = 0.e_1 + 1.e_2 = 1.e_2$, $T(e_2) = 0.e_1 + 1.e_2 = 1.e_2$

$$ M(T,\{e_1,e_2\}) = \left [\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{array} \right] $$

$T(e_1) = 0.e_1 + 0.e_2 = 0 $, $T(e_2) = 0.e_1 + 1.e_2 = 1.e_2$

How do i continue to get $v_1$ and $v_2$? I guess that answer should be in the following form $$v_1= a_1.e_1 + a_2.e_2$$
and $$v_2= a_1.e_1 + a_2.e_2$$

Hints are appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The kernel of T is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}$. If this is your first basis vector $v_1$, then the matrix of T will begin with $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. For the second basis vector, notice that $T\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Let $v_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Then the matrix of $T$ with respect to the new basis, $\{v_1,v_2\}$  is $[T(v_1)|T(v_2)]=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

Comment: How did you get $Null$ T is $\left [\begin{array}{cc} 1\\-1 \end{array} \right]$?

Comment: Look at the rref, and solve $1\cdot x+1\cdot y = 0$. Any vector satisfying this relationship will work.

Comment: So, you did rref to the first matrix and get first basis, $v_1$. So then we get second basis after we get rref of the second matrix? Thanks a lot, anyway!

Comment: The matrix of T is $[T(v_1) | T(v_2) ]$. I found the kernel because we need $T(v_1)$ is the zero vector. To find $v_2$, we need to satisfy that $T(v_2)=(0,1)$. I don't think rref will be useful in finding $v_2$.

Comment: What do you think about my attempt? I know i might be completely wrong.

Comment: All of your statements are correct, but the method seems to be increasing the complexity of the system...

Comment: I just saw your new edited answer so the answer is same as the second matrix? Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18074/discussion-between-user179313-and-reluctant-mathematician).